# WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

estoy teniendo problemas para entrenar un sistema de comentarios toxicos...

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
model = Sequential()
# Create the embedding layer 
model.add(Embedding(MAX_FEATURES+1, 32))
# Bidirectional LSTM Layer
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, activation='tanh')))
# Feature extractor Fully connected layers
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
# Final layer 
model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='BinaryCrossentropy', optimizer='Adam')

model.summary()
```

Model Summary me da los siguientes datos:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 embedding (Embedding)       (None, None, 32)          6400032   
                                                                 
 bidirectional (Bidirectiona  (None, 64)               16640     
 l)                                                              
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 128)               8320      
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 256)               33024     
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 128)               32896     
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 6)                 774       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 6,491,686
Trainable params: 6,491,686
Non-trainable params: 0
```

y cuando quiero correr la prediccion:

```
input_text = vectorizer('You freaking suck! I am going to hit you.')

res = model.predict(input_text)
```

me tira el siguiente error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, None) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.float32, name='embedding_input'), name='embedding_input', description="created by layer 'embedding_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-b290db637980> in <module>
----> 1 res = model.predict(input_text)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__predict_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1845, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1834, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1823, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1791, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 214, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "bidirectional" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 32)
    
    Call arguments received by layer "sequential" (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=int64)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

Alguien me podria ayudar por favor.

Comment: Prueba esto :
input_text = vectorizer(['You freaking suck! I am going to hit you.'])

Comment: Bueno, 1 paso más... ahora dice: : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gradio'

but: !pip install gradio
Requirement already satisfied: gradio in c:\users\txedo\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (3.6)